# Ubuntu stuck after creating live usb with unetbootin

Tags: boot, unetbootin

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.I have created a bootable usb for my friend using unetboot in my laptop. But when I turn on my laptop it goes to unetboot option with default and tab option thing and I cant get my laptop to open. I don't have any bootable usb or cd on my laptop. My Ubuntu wont boot. Please anyone help. I have some urgent works to do in my laptop.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to ask, but why don't you retry to do it. Make sure you have 2GB of free space.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to ask, but why don't you retry to do it. Make sure you have 2GB of free space.

Comment: Problem is now when i turn on my laptop ubuntu does not open. Screen shows a unetbootin screen . I need a way to cancel/disable this unetbootin  .

Comment: Are you making the disk on Ubuntu or Windows?

Comment: My friend need a Bootable usb for his laptop. I had a iso file, so by using unetboot i created the bootable usb and gave it to him. I just created a bootable usb nothing else...Why should it effect my laptop on startup?

Comment: Yes I know, but what operating system are you using UNetBootIn on

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Use Startup Utility Disk to do this. It is way easier

Comment: I know..but how do i solve the problem i am having at the moment?

Comment: Sorry... I have no idea how to fix it. I would try going to Startup to do it

Answer (score 0):

- Please shutdown the computer,
- and after that unplug the USB pendrive,
- and after that boot the computer again.

Maybe this makes the computer boot as usual again.

-o-

If it did not help, it seems Unetbootin used your hard disk drive as a target. What happens when you try the different options in the Unetbootin menu. Maybe it will start a live Ubuntu system, and you can use that system until you fix the problem.

For example, you can create a USB boot drive, boot from that drive, and repair the bootloader in your hard disk drive.

Maybe you should use another tool to create a USB boot drive. In Windows you can use **Rufus** or **Win32 Disk Imager**. In linux you can use **mkusb**.

-o-

If your computer does not start from its Unetbootin menu, I suggest that you borrow another computer, and try with one of these other tools, and this time, please check and double-check, that you will write to the USB pendrive, and not to some other drive. (mkusb was made in order to help identifying the target drive and avoid mistakes.)